# How to exactly copy what you see on your screen?

Tags: c#, copy, screen, screenshot

So I have searched for a while on how can you copy what's on your screen or take a screenshot, and I have found some solutions for example this method:

```cs
public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
{
  Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
  Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImg as Image);
  graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, newImg.Size);
  return newImg;
}
```

This method works fine, except that when you run an application as administrator, the screen shows something like "Are you sure? YES NO":

[image: Run as Adminstrator]

Or even on CTRL + ALT + DEL:

[image: ctrl+alt+del]

At these screens, these methods don't work as they will show a black screen, Also, **some applications will give a black screen on them** as they are like protected/not on your screen while other things on the screen appear normally.

Why is this happening? and how do I get what am I looking at EXACTLY on my screen?

**EDIT #1:**

Solution found using **PsExec**. (Thanks to Koray Elbek)

But still didn't fix the problem that happens with some applications as they will have a black box on them.

Why is this happening and how to get the correct screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

The following quote is from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1004864/How-do-I-get-Screenshot-when-machine-is-locked-Cpl)

> The logon screen is an isolated desktop running under
> NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM where you don't have access. To be able to use GUI
> on such private environment there are some shortcuts like [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/113267/how-to-take-screenshots-of-the-windows-logon-screen-2-geeky-tricks/),
> but the definitive tool is [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) It uses a service helper to run
> programs on a remote machine, or on a local machine as
> NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. The helper service opens a named pipe to
> communicate with local application to get commands and return status.
> PsExec is not redistribuitable and sources are not available, but
> exists an open version called [PaExec](https://www2.poweradmin.com/paexec/). You can download it and
> have a look... You should use PaExec to launch your app under
> NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM to have access to the DC of logon screen and
> capture images. But as I said this is an isolated DC so to catch
> snapshots from user screen and system screen you have to run 2
> instances of your app.

This answer was posted for a C++ question, but the principles are same for you also, you will need to use same approach for your C# application too.

Comment: Thank you so much, tested it and works fine on screens I have mentioned. But there's still one thing I didn't manage to fix, which is some applications will still give a black box on them. They are on the normal screen too, I tried running my program with SYSTEM but still didn't manage to get the correct screenshot. Why are these applications have a black box on them and how do I get the real screenshot? (Added screenshot on original post)

Comment: @user3425606 Ah okay, the black box problem is still happening for you. But unfortunately at the moment I'm unsure why that still happens. The only thing I can suggest is to try capturing the screen using Win32 API methods. Just to see if it makes a difference:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/765/how-to-capture-screen-using-c-sharp-net.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I think I tried all the screenshot methods and none of them are perfect. They all work but for some applications they still appear as black box. I have read an article about protecting applications from screen grabbing, and I have read that they use the black box technology. So I really think the black box is because these applications are protected, but I'm still trying to get the correct screenshot. I don't think it's a problem in the code. And am not sure if it's possible now...